# How to develop new WebRTC HTML5 webcam video samples ? getUserMedia()

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia, webcam-capture

I would like to develop a numer of demo WebRTC HTML5 video canvas apps, based on WebRTC samples from
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/
integrating some features and adding new ones.

I am especially interested to know if MS Windows + Firefox/ Chrome can support 2 independent webcam live video stream inputs ( Android can, Linux can)

I am interested to split 1 webcam video input stream into 2 halt FPS video streams.

Just tell me if you have tested all samples as above and they all worked for you.

Comment: We use WebRTC and display multiple streams with two way audio on one page in Chrome and Firefox for Linux, Mac OS and MS Windows environments. Please provide more details about your question. I don't think somebody can claim to test all the samples. It all depends what is required for your task. If you can specify what you've done and what is not working, there will be more replies.

Comment: Thank you Olga, I am reading now https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#def-constraint-frameRate to learn if I can arbitraty set frameRate video input/output to slow down webcam video stream input. At the same time I am trying to learn if input from 2 and more usb webcams can be combined into a single video stream (multi video tracks 2 single video stream and if MS Windows can support it.  Then I come to examples and new features I plan to implement, basing on the official MediaCapture manual https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#def-constraint-frameRate